# How to manage a multilayered dictionary, customize the columns, subtract column data, and add a new column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Thanks so much for the help!

I'm doing a json pull from Alphavantage. I'm trying to:

1. Convert the json data to a Pandas dataframe
2. Get the correct data to display correctly
3. Customize the column labels ('Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume')
4. Subtract data in column 'Close' from data in column 'Open'
5. Create a new column called 'Net' with data from number 4 above

I'm a total noob. This is actually my first real project and first time posting here. I'm still learning and experimenting. I'm sure there is a much easier way to do what I'm doing. I've spent countless hours researching and trying to figure this out. Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as rq

pull_type = 'TIME_SERIES_DAILY'
symbol = 'GOOG'
size = 'compact'
data_type = 'json'
api_key = 'XXX_MY_KEY_XXX'
url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?'
pull_parameters = {
    'function': pull_type,
    'symbol': symbol,
    'outputsize': size,
    'datatype': data_type,
    'apikey': api_key
}

pull = rq.get(url, params=pull_parameters)

data = pull.json()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['Time Series (Daily)'], orient='index')

df.columns = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

day_net = df['Open'] - df['Close']

print(day_net)
```

I'm getting so many exception errors. Too many to list. Still learning what they all mean. Any input and direction would be welcomed and much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show at least the first few exception error, that's where we'll be able to see what the problem might be.

Comment: New to this. Didn't see your comment until now. @U10-Forward answered it below. Thanks for commenting though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['Time Series (Daily)'], orient='index')
```

To:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['Time Series (Daily)'], orient='index').astype(float)
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much! You're a rockstar!

Comment: One more thing... Is this line of code actually doing anything? 

`df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Comment: @shaunbarbour Yes, it converts the index fro string to datetime, so you can do a lot of datetime functions with it

Answer (score 0):

So I know this is already answered, but I wanted to let you in on this too!

You could also use the open-source python wrapper:
https://github.com/RomelTorres/alpha_vantage

From your terminal run:

```
pip install alpha_vantage
```

Then you could just have your code be:

```
import alpha_vantage
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries

ts = TimeSeries(key=<key>, output_format='pandas')
data, meta_data = ts.get_daily(symbol='GOOG', outputsize='full')
# data is the DataFrame and meta_data is a dict
```

The documentation and repo is [here](https://github.com/RomelTorres/alpha_vantage)